# Java class as variable

Tags: java, oop, reflection

I am developing a game in Java, and I am trying to create enemies that can shoot projectiles. I am defining the base class for all enemy types, and I have already defined a projectile class. What I would like to do is define a class type variable in the base enemy class, and a shootProjectile() method that will create a new instance of the defined projectile class when called. Pseudo code:

```
public class EnemyClass extends GameCharacter {
        protected Class projectileType;
        protected int a;
        protected int b;

        // Constructor and other stuff here

        public void shootProjectile() {
            projectileType newProjectile = new projectileType(a, b);
        }
}

public class MyEnemySubClass extends EnemyClass {
        public MyEnemySubClass() {
            super();
            projectileType = MySuperProjectile;
        }
        // Rest of class stuff here
}

public class MySuperProjectile extends Projectile {
        public MySuperProjectile(parameter a, parameter b) {
              // Constructor stuff using a and b
        }
        // Other projectile-related stuff
}
```

The idea of course is that in the enemy sub classes all I need to do is define what class of projectile they shoot, and the shootProjectile() method in the base class will do the rest.

I'm not sure how to achieve this. I have looked at defining generics but not sure how to make this work for my purposes and I'm not sure I fully understand how they work. Is something like this even possible in Java, or would I need to override shootProjectile for each subclass of EnemyClass to create their own projectile while attacking?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: use `Class.newInstance()`. Also, use `Class<? extends Projectile>` so you can put the `newInstance` in a reference of `Projectile`

Comment: it would also be easier to add setter methods to your Projectile class in order to pass the values for a and b, as you don't know what constructor will be available.

Comment: Thank you for all the responses guys, plenty of different approaches to consider which is always nice to have! I'll try each one and see which one I prefer. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you do not need to use generics.

If you want different implementations of `Enemy` shoot different implementation of `Projectile` then just define abstract method  `Projectile shootProjectile()` in `Enemy` abstract class and implement it as you see fit in each `Enemy` subclass.

But if you for some reason insist on using them. Them add parameter `T` to `Enemy` class. And define the method as `T shootProjectile()`. Example:

```
abstract class Enemy<T extends Projectile> {
     abstract T shootProjectile();
}
```

And again. Do implementation in subclasses like:

```
class Sniper extends Enemy<SniperRifleBullet>{

    @Override
    SniperRifleBullet shootProjectile() {
        return new SniperRifleBullet();
    }
}

class Projectile{}

class SniperRifleBullet extends Projectile{}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have `Class.forName()`, `getClass().newInstance()`, the [prototype pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype_pattern), or [functional objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_object) as choices.  In the latter case, you would supply an object whose sole purpose was to create an instance of the required class (that would be your `projectileType` variable).

Answer (score 0):

A better approach is to use a "projectile factory".... Something like this:
 - Create a interface ProjectileFactory with one single method like createProjectil.
 - Change the BaseEnemyClass to have a instance of ProjectileFactory instead of have a Class.

Now you can construct your Enemies with a factory and can have enemies that shoot the same projectile class with especific parameters.